# What is a "share rate"?

Tags: mining-pools, hash, mining-pool-shares

What is a "share rate" one can find in a mining pool dashboard?

I understand what a hash-rate is, and how that applies to myself (miner), as well as to the pool or the network. I also understand to some degree what shares of a block being mined are. But what is then the shown share rate (shown as a value between 0 and 1, as well as in shares/s).

Comment: I tried to improve your question a bit, please check whether my changes are in accord to your original intention.

Comment: Do you mean as in the number of shares you have found?

Comment: I wrote some more. It's probably just an artifact of a bad UI without any decent explanations. At least now I know it's not something important or well-known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which pool your mining, this is usually representative of how many valid shares are being passed back to the pool.

It has been displayed in a decimal fraction it seems, so 0.985 would be an amount of 98.5% valid shares returned.